# Popular science on carcinisation

Tags: evolution, morphology

Carcinisation is described succinctly in a Wikipedia entry. The entry references few scientific publications regarding the subject. But are there any popular scientific articles describing and giving examples of carcinisation in the layman's terms?

Comment: [GoogleScholar > Carcinisation](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&q=Carcinisation&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=)

Comment: This is the most cited publication regarding the topic: http://research.nhm.org/pdfs/11727/11727.pdf